# passing non-url encoded parameters to an ajax call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I am trying to pass parameters from my website to a couchdb server through a node.js server.
I absolutely need to pass {} in a url. Not a string, not an empty object, the actual {} characters. It is used to define the `end_key` parameter in couchdb views.

At the moment, my call goes like this :

```
let url = "/trades";
let ajax_options = {
    data:{
        design_name:'bla',
        view_name:'blabla',
        params_view:{
            group_level:2,
            start_key:["1",0],
            end_key:["1",{}]
        }
    }
};
$.ajax(url,ajax_options).then((res) => { ... });
```

when it passes through `NodeJs` and the `nano` library with

```
db.view(req.query.design_name, req.query.view_name, req.query.params_view)
```

the `end_key` object in `params_view` becomes `["1"]` instead of `["1",{}]` which I would like to see.

I have verified that with the correct value for `end_key`, the view gives me the expected result.

How to prevent that behavior from occurring ?

Comment: If you just want the characters, why don't you pass them as a string?

Comment: tried that as well but couchdb needs to get {}, not "{}", to interpret the end_key correctly.

Comment: a workaround for string keys is to just add a "0" to the end of it and that does it but I'd rather be able to use the universal solution.

Comment: Another workaround is to use the character `"\ufff0"` since it's the highest unicode character.

Comment: Thks Alexis. Would that work for numbers as well ?

Comment: @Chapo as far as I remember it worked for numbers too.